# Using python to move the origin of a selected object to the bottom center of itself

Tags: python

new to python and scripting in blender and i cant seem to figure out out to move the origin of an object using python.

Also, what would be the best way to calculate the center and bottom of a mesh? Looping through the vertices and calculating using those?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move an object's origin to the center of its bounding box?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70098/how-to-move-an-objects-origin-to-the-center-of-its-bounding-box)

Comment: Or: [Changing object origin to arbitrary point without origin_set()?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/35825/31447), [Setting mesh's origin in python (2.8)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140605/setting-meshs-origin-in-python-2-8) -> the list goes on...

Comment: Sort of, i can move it to the center of the mesh but i cant figure out out to move it to the lowest z point in the mesh.

Comment: [Translate object using lowest Z value python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73698/translate-object-using-lowest-z-value-python)

Comment: Another one for all mesh objects: [Set origin to bottom center of multiple objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/42105/31447)

Comment: batFINGER script in the 'Set Origin to bottom center...' one looks like it would be it but its written for an older version. is there a way to convert it to 2.8

Comment: I figured it out thank you

Comment: Glad I could help @TYLRwithspaces