# Python: Getting range center of object

Tags: python

**Edit**: The problem was that I did not update the scene after scaling the object.

I am trying to move the origin of the object to the center of its bounding box.

I tried this solution [Get center of geometry of an object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62040/get-center-of-geometry-of-an-object)

```
o = bpy.context.object

vcos = [ o.matrix_world @ v.co for v in o.data.vertices ]
findCenter = lambda l: ( max(l) + min(l) ) / 2

x,y,z  = [ [ v[i] for v in vcos ] for i in range(3) ]
center = [ findCenter(axis) for axis in [x,y,z] ]

bpy.context.scene.cursor.location = center

bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR')
```

This is how it always ends up:
[image]

Clearly, the origin doesn't sit at the center of the bounding box. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The next code snippet from answer (below code used in post above) uses the bounding box. `global_bbox_center`

Comment: For some reason both of the examples give me the same results. Which seems to be closer to center of mass than center of bounding box.