# Getting x,y,z coordinates of objects in blender API FOR MULTIPLE OBJECTS

Tags: rendering, objects

I am trying to calculate the cooordinates of the center of a group of objects using this code:

```
obj = bpy.context.active_object                                             
vcos = [ obj.matrix_world * v.co for v in obj.data.vertices ]                     
findCenter = lambda l: ( max(l) + min(l) ) / 2      
x,y,z  = [ [ v[i] for v in vcos ] for i in range(3) ]      
center = [ findCenter(axis) for axis in [x,y,z] ]
```

The problem is that "bpy.context.active_object" returns only the (bpy_struct, Object) of one OBJECT only (the first to render) and does not consider the other objects. As a result the obtained X,Y,Z coordinates are only correct for one object and not all of them.

Any solution?

Amir

Comment: try `bpy.context.selected_objects`

Comment: @Gorgious: This gives ('list' object has no attribute 'data') this is attribute of vertices used later in the code.          I use this code after rendering, so I have a loop and I render hide some objects and render others and in each time I render an individual object I wanna get it X,Y,Z coordinates. For some rason, when I print the coordinates of (center) of each object rendered separately in the loop, i find the same coordinates and I find "obj" is only referring to the first rendered object and does not change when I render the other objects.                             Any advise????

Comment: What is not clear for me: do you want the center considering all objects at once (so 1 center for all) or the center for each object? (@Gorgious)

Answer (score 2):

Take this image :
[image]

`bpy.context.active_object` only gives a reference to the active object in the given context. This is `Cube.002`, with the light orange outline.

`Cube` is selected, but it is not the active object. (dark orange outline).

When you type `bpy.context.selected_objects` in the blender console you get an unordered list of all the selected objects.

```
>>> bpy.context.selected_objects
[bpy.data.objects['Cube'], bpy.data.objects['Cube.002']]
```

In python you can iterate through a list of objects with a `for` loop. ([Documentation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)) Your code, which is valid for one object, can be translated for a list to :

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    if obj.type != 'MESH':
        continue
    # Sidenote : Use @ instead of * for element-wise multiplication in matrices          
    vcos = [ obj.matrix_world @ v.co for v in obj.data.vertices ]                     
    findCenter = lambda l: ( max(l) + min(l) ) / 2      
    x,y,z  = [ [ v[i] for v in vcos ] for i in range(3) ]      
    center = [ findCenter(axis) for axis in [x,y,z] ]
    
    print(center)
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: Given the OP's new question might pay to put the type checking in loop, _eg_ `if obj.type != 'MESH' : continue` to avoid trying to process vertices of non mesh objects.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196663/error-when-processing-a-blender-file-in-python

Comment: @batFINGER Good point ! Edited answer

Answer (score 1):

**Bounds center is the middle of the bounding box.**

The local positions of the axis oriented bounding box of a mesh are generated for us and available  in the object's bounding box property in local coordinates.

The average of the bounding boxes 8 corner coordinates give the local center, which can be converted to global by multiplying by matrix world of owner.

Pros, only summing 8 coordinates per object and matrix multiplying once  Using the object's vertices is unnecessary overhead.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector
# mesh objects in scene
scene = bpy.context.scene
mesh_obs = [o for o in scene.objects if o.type == 'MESH']

for ob in mesh_obs:
    bbox_local_center = sum((Vector(b) for b in ob.bound_box), Vector()) / 8
    center = ob.matrix_world @ bbox_local_center
    print(f"{ob.name} {center}")
```

Thought this rang a bell, possible duplicate and source of question code.  [Get center of geometry of an object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62040/get-center-of-geometry-of-an-object)  *If you source code from elsewhere, providing a link gives context.*

**Note.**

If instead you wish to get the "global bounding box" of all recommend using numpy.

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

# mesh objects in scene
scene = bpy.context.scene
mesh_obs = [o for o in scene.objects if o.type == 'MESH']
# stack global coords of bboxes of all objects in scene
coords = np.vstack(
    (np.dot(
        np.hstack(
            (np.array(ob.bound_box),
             np.ones(8).reshape(8, 1))
             ), 
        ob.matrix_world.transposed()
        )
    for ob in mesh_obs)
    )

#bottom front left corner, top, right back corner    
print(coords.min(), coords.max())
```