# Find location of an object with respect to a moved origin

Tags: python

I have an (simple) object for which I moved the origin outside of the object to be able to rotate around it. Is there a way to read this given offset with python?

When using bpy.data.objects['Cube'].location , only the location of the origin is given. So basicly I need the locations of the vertexes wrt the origin. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: The origin is some arbitrary point designated as (0, 0, 0) in local coordinates.  All vert coords are wrt origin.   Because it is arbitrary there is no saved previous location if adjusted. However the default origin of most meshes is also the centre of geometry. (mean of bounding box coordinates).    _Coords of COG is the vector describing its offset from origin._ An empty parent  is another way to consider adding pivot point.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62040/get-center-of-geometry-of-an-object

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The other thread was quite helpful.